# Why would I need to use a virtual modifier in a c# class?

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class Delivery
{
// Primary key, and one-to-many relation with Customer
   public int DeliveryID { get; set; }
   public virtual int CustomerID { get; set; }
   public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }

// Properties
   string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Can someone explain why they Customer information is coded with virtual. What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess you are using EF.

What happens when you make a `NavigationProperty` virtual is that EF dynamically creates a derived class.
**That class implements functionality that allows for lazy loading and other tasks like maintaining relations that EF performs for you**.

Just to get the idea your sample class dynamically becomes something like this:

```
public class DynamicEFDelivery : Delivery 
{
   public override Customer Customer 
   { 
     get
     {
       return // go to the DB and actually get the customer
     } 
     set
     {
       // attach the given customer to the current entity within the current context
       // afterwards set the Property value
     }
   }
}
```

You can easily see this while debugging, the actual instance types of your EF classes have very weird names, since they are generated on the fly.

Answer (score 5):

Judging by the comments, you are learning Entity Framework?

virtual here would mean you are trying to use lazy loading - when related items like Customer can be loaded by EF automatically

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx

*For example, when using the Princess entity class defined below, the related unicorns will be loaded the first time the Unicorns navigation property is accessed:*

```
public class Princess 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<Unicorn> Unicorns { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> > Can someone explain why they Customer information is coded with virtual. What does it mean?

The *virtual* keyword means that a super class derived from this base class (i.e. Delivery) can *override* that method.

If the method was not marked as *virtual* then it would not be possible to *override* that method.